# empty array to convert file to array

Tags: java

I try to convert a file to an array of integers, do not know where my mistake is that when I print the array empty array throws

I leave my method , thanks you

```
public int[] ConvertToArray(File xd) throws IOException {     

 String sCadena;int i=0;
    int[]array;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(xd); 
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int lNumeroLineas = 0;
    while ((sCadena = bf.readLine())!=null) {
        lNumeroLineas++;
    }
    array = new int[lNumeroLineas];
    while ((sCadena = bf.readLine())!=null) {
        lNumeroLineas++;
        array[i]=Integer.parseInt(sCadena);
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already at the end of file after your first `while` loop completes.

So reading from `BufferedReader` object `bf` again after first while loop ends will always give you `null`(End of file) and **second iteration will never run**.

Also in the `for loop` you  are printing `array[i]` however `for loop` is iterating over `j variable`

You can do it like this with help of `ArrayList`:

```
public int[] ConvertToArray(File xd) throws IOException {     

 String sCadena;

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(xd); 
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int lNumeroLineas = 0;
    while ((sCadena = bf.readLine())!=null) {
        lNumeroLineas++;
        array.add(Integer.parseInt(sCadena.trim())); //always recomended to trim(); to remove trailing whitespaces.
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(array.get(j));
    }
    return covertIntegers(array);
}
```

**Edited:** If you want to send `int[]` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>` without using any external libraries.

```
    public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: In accordance to what ? Do you want to return an integer array from the above method?

Comment: Glad to help ! Please accept the answer if your problem is solved, as it helps everyone who visits this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file with two loops but open only once. Reopen the file reader before the second `while` and it will work.

Comment: @ZbynekThank you very much for your contribution